# Excel Conditional Formatting - Two conditions

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I work for an accounting firm and I need a reminder to let us know when new credit card statements are available online every month. Here's what I need:

If the cell immediately to the left is not empty AND the date in that cell is more than 30 days ago, change the color of the cell to green.

The formula below seems to work for the date portion but I'm not sure how to add the additional "if cell is not empty" condition.

=TODAY()-(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,-1))>30

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvBmk.png)

Comment: =and(condition 1, condition 2)

Answer (score 0):

Jeff.

Try this way, changing the address to your needs:

```
=AND(K$6<>"",TODAY()-K$6>30)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this, but for some reason it's still not working.

=AND((OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,-1))<>””,TODAY()-(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,-1))>30)

Answer (score 0):

I took your formula for the conditional apart, put it back together, and it doesn't work.  You do have a couple spaces in there, but fixing that didn't change matters.  So, I checked all pieces of the formula in Excel proper, they work.  Back to conditional, it doesn't.  Used the formula similar to leal32b above, it worked beautifully.

I went out to Google, and apparently Excel conditional formatting does not play well with indirect addresses.  So you aren't crazy, but you probably aren't going to get it work.  Remember to remove $ signs as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Julia! I guess I'll just use the cell name as you and leal32b suggested.